# RSA Encryption: Why do different totient calculations lead to correct results for some examples and incorrect results for other examples?

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa

For a class project, I am creating a manual implementation of RSA encryption. It is not meant to be cryptographically secure, it is meant only as a proof of understanding.

I have created a program that can generate valid key pairs, but I noticed that different calculations for the totient lead to correct answers for different online examples.

For instance, p and q are prime numbers, calculating the totient as:

```
lcm((p - 1), (q - 1))
```

gives the correct private key for [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Example) and ["A very simple example of RSA encryption"](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html), but incorrect private keys for ["A slightly less simple example of the RSA algorithm"](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html) and [the example in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYasb426Yjk).

While calculating the totient as:

```
((p - 1) * (q - 1))
```

produces correct and incorrect private keys in the opposite examples.

Why is this and how can I calculate the totient and private key so that the private key produced is always correct?

[My program.](https://pastebin.com/CsnGTmDn)

Comment: *Why is this...* -- [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Also, if you're going to write your own RSA implementation, you better have one that works correctly on-hand, so that you can compare what the working version(s) do, and what you are not doing.

Comment: try to avoid having so many exterior links, the question is nicely asked but once the link are broken it will become very difficult for people to get value from your post

Comment: Please include all necessary information in the question itself.

Comment: See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Use a debugger to inspect your intermediate values or print them out and compare them to the correct ones. You can also test each of your functions separately to make sure they're correct.

Comment: @BessieTheCow, I have used a debugger and watched the relevant variables. The problem is that when I compare my results to known good results I get the right answer for some and the wrong answer for others, but if I change one line of code, as indicated in my question, the outcomes are reversed. As in, the results that previously matched the known good results no longer match, and the results that previously did not match now match,

Comment: Forget about the two different versions of the program. Pick one version and debug it first. Check the value of every variable and the return value of every function. Which is the first incorrect value you can find?

Comment: @BessieTheCow I did that previously and the first incorrect value is d, the private exponent and the final value I am trying to find. I think my error is not in my programming but rather in my understanding of the difference between phi(n) and lambda(n). 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60938226/can-there-be-more-than-one-valid-private-exponent-for-a-given-p-q-and-e-in-rsa

Comment: No, the difference between the totient functions aren't relevant here. I can tell you for sure that there is at least one separate bug in your program. You know that the first incorrect value occurs here: `d = phi - abs(modInv(e, phi));`, which computes the modular inverse. If you look at the pseudocode for the extended euclidean algorithm on Wikipedia, it includes `if t < 0 then t := t + n`. You don't have this part. Instead, you take the absolute value of the return value of `modInv`. Are they really the same?

Comment: You know `e` is correct and `phi` is correct, but when you try to compute the inverse of `e` mod `phi` the value is wrong. Therefore there has to be a bug in your modular inverse computation.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Why isn't the difference between the totient functions relevant? Changing which totient function is used leads to some examples to be correct and others to be incorrect, but every example I've tried is correct with one of them. If taking the absolute value is not equivalent to what Wikipedia concludes, then I should change modInv to return `old_s + phi` instead of just `old_s` and I should remove the `abs()` function from `d = phi - abs(modInv(e, phi));` to just `d = phi - modInv(e, phi);`?

Edit: Tried the edits I asked about, they do not lead to correct results.

Comment: He saying the choice of lamda function versus phi function is irrelevant because *either* choice gives you incorrect answers, so just pick one and debug it. Also, you're being advised that your bug must be in your `modInv` method, so concentrate on that.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk My confusion is that they give incorrect answers in _opposite_ scenarios. Between them, they always produce the correct answer. I also think the error is more likely to be in my calculation of `d` rather than in the `modInv` function since watching the variables in modInv, they all match the examples demonstrated on Wikipedia and other sites.

Comment: d is just e inverse mod phi. Why are you subtracting it from phi in this line: `d = phi - abs(modInv(e, phi));` ?

Comment: "Between them, they always produce the correct answer." That's just a coincidence. Your `modInv` function is not the same as the one on Wikipedia. As I said before, the one on Wikipedia adds the modulus to the result if it is negative, but you don't do that. Also, why are you subtracting the inverse from `phi`? The fact that both lambda functions give an incorrect answer at least in one case proves that there is a bug somewhere else in your code. If the lambda function is the only problem then one of them should be always correct.

Comment: I'm trying to guide you to being able to spot the bug yourself, since in the long term that will help you more than me just telling you the bug. But it's hard to do that if you keep holding on to your own (incorrect) assumptions. There can be multiple bugs in your program, and a program with a bug can sometimes output correct values. Don't assume where the bug is. If you're so sure that your `modInv` function is correct, why don't you test it against a bunch of values? According to your `modInv` function, what is the modular inverse of 7 mod 15?

Comment: You need to 1. add the modulus to the result in your `modInv` function **only if the result is negative**, and 2. change your `d` computation to `d = modInv(e, phi)`. Those are the bugs that I can see right now, but there may be more.